# parse email out of a string coming back from web GET method

Tags: c#

I am calling a web GET method. It uses stream reader to communicate with the service and in the end, I get lines of email addressees in the following string format.

How can I get email address out of the following string?

[{\"email\": \"johndoe@microsoft.com\", \"created\": \"2015-01-20 22:16:55\"}]

Comment: I would split based on the \ character and then remove or trim off the first character which would be ". I have a feeling you need something a little more cleaner and manageable but if its the same format all the time. What @codebased suggested seems much more reliable!

Comment: You could use dynamic data type .dynamic data = Json.Decode(json); and then you should have data.email

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code, which is generated using json2csharp.net :)

```
public class Address
{
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string created { get; set; }
}
```

And then you can use DataContractJsonSerializer class to convert it to object.

```
var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Address));
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(
    UTF8Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("{\"email\": \"johndoe@microsoft.com\", \"created\": \"2015-01-20 22:16:55\"}")))
{
    var result = serializer.ReadObject(memoryStream) as Address;
    Console.WriteLine(result.email);
}
```

HTH